# Python: Why is this string invalid?

Tags: python, syntax

**SOLVED**

I have this string:

```
'  ServerAlias {hostNameshort}.* www.{hostNameshort}.*'.format(hostNameshort=hostNameshort)
```

But it keeps giving me a syntax error. The line is supposed to be this bash equivalent:

```
echo "    ServerAlias ${hostOnly}.* www.${hostOnly}.*" >> $prjFile
```

Mind you the first string is a part of a myFile.write function but that isn't the issue, I can't even get the string to make enough sense for it to let me run the program.

Traceback:

```
  File "tomahawk_alpha.py", line 89
    '  ServerAlias {hostNameshort}.* www.{hostNameshort}.*'.format(hostNameshort=hostNameshort)
                                                          ^
```

But no matter how I change that `'` symbol it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

In response to @mgilson:

```
    myFile = open(prjFile, 'w+')
    myFile.write("<VirtualHost 192.168.75.100:80>"
                 "  ServerName www.{hostName}".format(hostName=hostName)
                 '  ServerAlias {hostNameshort}.* www.{hostNameshort}.*'.format(hostNameshort=hostNameshort)
                 "  DocumentRoot ", prjDir, "/html"
                 '  CustomLog "\"|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/class/',prjCode,'/\{hostName}.log.%Y%m%d\" urchin"'.format(hostName=hostName)
                 "</VirtualHost>")
    myFile.close()
```

I had each line in it's own myFile.write line, but it only produced the first line and then quit. So I assumed calling it once and spacing it like that would create intended result.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the string.  Are all your parenthesis closed on the previous line?

Comment: In your traceback it looks like you removed the error type.  Can you include this so we can better diagnose the problem?

Comment: The problem might be on some the previous line as mgilson mentioned.  You chould also check that all the `'` are closed as well.

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Seems to be working in both [Python 2.7](http://ideone.com/43v1ql) and [3](http://ideone.com/D7ZdN5).

Comment: Yeah, you have consecutive strings separated by nothing but whitespace. Perhaps you wanted the plus operator?

Comment: Odd, I am in 2.7.3 and it's puking. Well, I forgot to add the \n to each line.

Comment: You can stack string literals like that, but not formatted strings.

Comment: I want each to be on individual lines, btw.

Comment: Okay so even if I do a write.myFile on each line it doesn't output everything in the file.

Comment: Don't include the solution in the question. Choose an answer that solves your problem and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of syntax errors.  However, you may want to look at using a triply quoted strings instead - much easier to modify in the long run:

```
myFile.write("""<VirtualHost 192.168.75.100:80>
               ServerName www.{hostName}
               ServerAlias {hostNameshort}.* www.{hostNameshort}.*
               DocumentRoot {prjDir}/html
               CustomLog "\"|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/class/{prjCode}/\{hostName}.log.%Y%m%d\" urchin"
             </VirtualHost>""".format(hostName=hn, hostNameshort=hns, prjDir=prjd, prjCode=prjc))
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, and I am going to use this triply quoted system with .format more often. Very nice!

Answer (score 4):

Automatic string concatenation only works with string literals:

```
"foo"  "bar"
```

results in `"foobar"`

But, the following won't work:

```
("{}".format("foo") 
 "bar")
```

which is analogous to what you are doing.  The parser sees something like this:

```
"{}".format("foo") "bar"
```

(because it joins lines where there are unterminated parenthesis) and that is clearly not valid syntax.  To fix it, you need to concatenate the strings explicitly.  e.g:

```
("{}".format("foo") +
 "bar")
```

Or use string formatting on the entire string, not just one piece of it at a time.